# MS CRM Online : Get records where there no associated record

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Need help want to get account records where contacts are not associated with account in a fetch xml report as my CRM is Online.
Tried in advanced find but not able to get it.

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a FetchXML that tells you that accounts are not associated with a contact

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="account">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="primarycontactid" />
    <attribute name="telephone1" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <order attribute="name" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="primarycontactid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Thank you…It is working as expected.
I need the scenario in between case and custom entity. The case and custom having 1 to N relationship.
Is there any way to achieve this also.

Comment: To be honest, the accounts returned from that search might be associated with contacts but the accounts have no primary contact.

Comment: This answer is not correct. In Dynamics CRM it is simply not possible to meet the requirement using Fetch XML.

Comment: she just wants the FetchXML wants nothing else will as a template. It is not to be so

Comment: Thank you all for your time , as the fetch xml did not work . I have created custom flag in case entity when the custom entity record is associating to case I am making the flag as true. When all associated records are deleted making the flag as false using a custom workflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="incident">
    <attribute name="title" />
    <attribute name="ticketnumber" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="incidentid" />
    <attribute name="caseorigincode" />
    <order attribute="title" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="customerid" operator="null" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```